# Why must promise's final_suspend be noexcept?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-coroutine

Is it simply because `promise.final_suspend()`, as I see [in the standard draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#5), is called out of the `try` block?

Or, in other words (I'm not sure if it is indeed equivalent to the above, though), is it to guarantee that exceptions escaping the coroutine are only those escaping the orignal *`function-body`* (at least those not handled via `promise.unhandled_exception()`)?